# How to make a layout like S Health for android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a layout like S Health (Right side of picture)

[image]

To me it seems like the layout is an ActionBar with a TabHost and a ScrollView.

The ScrollView then seems to be a vertical linear layout with a SurfaceView at the top.

My question is, am I right in thinking that I can use a SurfaceView to create a chart similar to the one pictured and then place other views under for the text and graphs?

How can a lock the ScrollView from moving up and down if the user starts by moving the chart horizontally?

Comment: if you SurfaceView, that respondes for displaying chart, will override processing touch method and return true in it, then if you will touch you SurfaceView, parent view (in your case LinearLayout and its parent ScrollView) will not process your touch. So everything will be good.

Comment: Also you need to think about how many chart items will you have. 20? 30? 40? Maybe it is better to create horizontal recycler view and every vertical bar of char will be item of this recycler view. This will save your memory from many views, that will be out of the screen.

Comment: Thank you!  Using a horizontal recycler seems very logical and is exactly the type of advice I was hoping to get from asking this question.

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin Inside of the dark grey circle the text changes color to white.  If the number is half in the circle and half out only the part of the the number that is in the circle will be white.  Do you know how to achieve this effect?

Comment: I think you need two type of views, one type will be ordinary numbers with their gray color. And second tipe is your circle. Then we need to think about details of realisation. Will grey circle be always in center of list of numbers or not? But in general it will some custom view, that will be draw circle and draw two text with white colors (left date and right date), and it will draw text only inside this circle. In this way will be acheived effect that you want. Probably you will need some masks to do that.

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin Makes sense.  How would you do the bars of the chart?   I really like how with S Health they resize based on the highest visible bar.

Comment: I think you will need to go through array of bar information (i think from your side there is some information about chart) and choose max value this bar will have max height. Other heights will compute like maxHeight/maxValue * currentValue